# WSO2 proxy service to send files to SFTP server using SSH cannot authenticate

Tags: ssh, wso2, sftp

I am trying to send files to SFTP server (SSH) using a WSO2 proxy service, but it appears the "transport.vfs.SFTPIdentities" and "transport.vfs.SFTPIdentityPassPhrase" parameters are not being applied when using the "transport.vfs.ReplyFileURI" parameter.

The proxy is picking up the incoming file, and attempting to send it to the SFTP server, but authorization is failing. (com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException: Auth fail)

Note: I have an Inbound Endpoint configured using the same properties and values which successfully connects to the server and picks up incoming files without issue.

Has anyone configured a proxy service or endpoint to ***send*** files to an SFTP server using SSH?  What am I missing?

The proxy configuration:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<proxy name="MyProxyService" startOnLoad="true" transports="vfs" xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
    <target>
        <inSequence>
            <property expression="$trp:FILE_NAME" name="theFileName" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
            <log level="custom">
                 <property expression="$ctx:theFileName" name="Processing file"/>
            </log>
            <property name="OUT_ONLY" scope="default" type="STRING" value="true"/>
            <respond/>
        </inSequence>
        <outSequence/>
        <faultSequence/>
    </target>
    <parameter name="transport.vfs.SFTPUserDirIsRoot">false</parameter>
    <parameter name="transport.vfs.ReplyFileURI">vfs:sftp://user@sftp.site/In?transport.vfs.AvoidPermissionCheck=true</parameter>
    <parameter name="transport.PollInterval">30</parameter>
    <parameter name="transport.vfs.FileURI">file://c:/TEMP</parameter>
    <parameter name="transport.vfs.ContentType">text/plain</parameter>
    <parameter name="transport.vfs.ActionAfterProcess">MOVE</parameter>
    <parameter name="transport.vfs.SFTPIdentities">/keys/my_private_key.ppk</parameter>
    <parameter name="transport.vfs.ActionAfterFailure">NONE</parameter>
    <parameter name="transport.vfs.FileNamePattern">.*</parameter>
    <parameter name="transport.vfs.MoveAfterProcess">file://c:/TEMP/Archive</parameter>
    <parameter name="transport.vfs.SFTPIdentityPassPhrase">passphrase</parameter>
</proxy>
```

The relevant stack trace:

```
...

[2020-05-14 15:59:52,960] [EI-Core]  INFO - SftpClientFactory [JSCH] Authentications that can continue: publickey,keyboard-interactive,password
[2020-05-14 15:59:52,960] [EI-Core]  INFO - SftpClientFactory [JSCH] Next authentication method: publickey
[2020-05-14 15:59:52,960] [EI-Core]  INFO - SftpClientFactory [JSCH] Disconnecting from sftp.site port 22
[2020-05-14 15:59:52,960] [EI-Core] ERROR - VFSTransportSender cannot resolve replyFile
org.apache.commons.vfs2.FileSystemException: Could not connect to SFTP server at "sftp://user@sftp.site/".
    at org.apache.commons.vfs2.provider.sftp.SftpFileProvider.doCreateFileSystem(SftpFileProvider.java:108)
    at org.apache.commons.vfs2.provider.AbstractOriginatingFileProvider.getFileSystem(AbstractOriginatingFileProvider.java:155)
    at org.apache.commons.vfs2.provider.AbstractOriginatingFileProvider.findFile(AbstractOriginatingFileProvider.java:119)
    at org.apache.commons.vfs2.provider.AbstractOriginatingFileProvider.findFile(AbstractOriginatingFileProvider.java:88)
    at org.apache.commons.vfs2.impl.DefaultFileSystemManager.resolveFile(DefaultFileSystemManager.java:747)
    at org.apache.commons.vfs2.impl.DefaultFileSystemManager.resolveFile(DefaultFileSystemManager.java:626)
    at org.apache.synapse.transport.vfs.VFSTransportSender.writeFile(VFSTransportSender.java:233)
    at org.apache.synapse.transport.vfs.VFSTransportSender.sendMessage(VFSTransportSender.java:194)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.base.AbstractTransportSender.invoke(AbstractTransportSender.java:119)
    at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine$TransportNonBlockingInvocationWorker.run(AxisEngine.java:626)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.apache.commons.vfs2.FileSystemException: Could not connect to SFTP server at "sftp.site".
    at org.apache.commons.vfs2.provider.sftp.SftpClientFactory.createConnection(SftpClientFactory.java:268)
    at org.apache.commons.vfs2.provider.sftp.SftpFileProvider.doCreateFileSystem(SftpFileProvider.java:97)
    ... 12 more
Caused by: com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException: Auth fail
    at com.jcraft.jsch.Session.connect(Session.java:512)
    at com.jcraft.jsch.Session.connect(Session.java:183)
    at org.apache.commons.vfs2.provider.sftp.SftpClientFactory.createConnection(SftpClientFactory.java:264)
    ... 13 more
```

Comment: What version of jsch are you using?

Comment: Using jsch-0.1.54 - also to note, this version can connect successfully to the same server (using same ppk file and passphrase) in an Inbound Endpoint configuration using the same transport.vfs.SFTP* properties.  Issue seems to be that those properties are not applied in the vfs Proxy Service for the transport.vfs.ReplyFileURI connection